# R: Passing a list of model objects to broom::glance with purrr produces unexpected errors

Tags: r, vectorization, purrr, survey, broom

I am trying to extract information using `broom::glance()` from `survey` models. While I can extract coefficients and other model results from each object using `broom:tidy()`, I sometimes receive an error that the object I am passing does not exist when I try to obtain information via `broom::glance()`. I am trying to understand how to address the errors in using `glance()`.

Specifically, it looks like any time I pass a list of `survey` objects to `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` and call `broom::glance()` within those functions - especially when piping the lists - I attain an error akin to ""Error in .svycheck(design) : object '.' not found".

In the code below, I reproduce the error repeatedly and try to pinpoint the source of the issue. It is difficult to tell if this is a consequence of `purrr`, `survey`, or `broom` having unexpected behavior. What I am expecting is `glance` to return an error that the model type I passed to it is not supported or the model information it usually provides.

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(survey)
library(broom)

# Create example list of data.frames
df_list <- data.frame(z = rnorm(20),
                      y = rnorm(20)) %>%
  list() %>%
  rep(2)

# Turn data.frames into design objects
objs_survey <- df_list %>%
  purrr::map(~ survey::svydesign(
    data = .x, ids = ~ 1, weights = ~ 1
  ))

# Fit models
mods_survey <- objs_survey %>%
  purrr::map(~ survey::svyglm(formula = y ~ z, design = .))

# Works with tidy
mods_survey %>% purrr::map( ~ broom::tidy(.))

# But doesn't work with glance
# "Error in .svycheck(design) : object '.' not found"
mods_survey %>% purrr::map( ~ broom::glance(.))

# Since it looks like the issue is
# the design argument is looking for
# .x and this may be a purrr issue
# let's avoid purrr

# First try manually on a single data.frame

# 1 df: Assigning design without %>% - WORKS
survey::svyglm(formula = y ~ z,
               design = objs_survey[[1]]) %>%
  broom::glance()

# 1d df: Assigning design with %>% - same error
objs_survey[[1]] %>% survey::svyglm(formula = y ~ z,
                                    design = .) %>%
  broom::glance()

# Also issues with lapply - same error
lapply(objs_survey, function(.) {
  survey::svyglm(formula = y ~ z,
                 design = .) %>%
    broom::glance(.)
})
```

Comment: This may almost certainly be an ssue where curly braces will fix things. Will check shortly.